# Intermediate Certificate Authority (CA) Installation Instructions for Microsoft IIS

Tags: iis-7, certificate-authority

I am following the Intermediate Certificate Authority (CA) Installation Instructions for Microsoft IIS from [this](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO16588) link. I completed the step 1 and step 2 but in step 3 they said "*From the left pane, click Intermediate Certification Authorities*" I don't know what they trying to say. I was not able to find even left pane :(

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment, two options are available to you:

1) if your machine is a member of workgroup, then simply run the following command:

```
certutil -addstore CA c:\temp\cacert.cer
```

2) if your machine is a member of Active Directory, you can distribute CA certificate to all AD forest members by publishing the certificate to Active Directory:

```
certutil -dspublish -f c:\temp\cacert.cer SubCA
```

in both commands replace fictional path (to CA cert file) to an actual one.